# image style (imagecache) images are not being created

Tags: 7, media

Currently i am unable to create images that get resized automaticaly according to the different image styles.

This includes the default styles such as thumbnail as well as the custom created styles.

I have checked the "Public file system path" as well as the "Temporary directory" (under Configuration > File system).

Both of the directories exist. 
The file permissions are good on the directories (777).

The original file that's uploaded gets created.
It's just the scaled images that aren't getting created.

Any help with this problem would be very welcome.
If there is already a solution somewhere (which means i searched for the wrong terms), a link to that would be very appreciated.

edit:

I can't find anything in the logfile either, except for messages like :

type : page not found

message: sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/fotoslider/slider_images/testbeeld20130103005.jpg

Comment: Is this only happening for one field, or site-wide? Have you cleared Drupal's cache/imagecache cache?

Comment: Does the preview image work on the image styles (the hot air balloon?)  Do you see this in the filesystem?

Comment: this is happening site-wide, in any node-type. The hot air balloon gets made when creating a new image style.

Comment: Does this happen with all themes, including the stock ones like Garland and Bartik?

Comment: Does this directory contain some images?
sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/fotoslider/slider_images/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was fixed when I changed the theme to another one, and back, as per @MPD suggestion.

Comment: @MPD - Stumbled on here after poking at various solutions for nearly an hour. Can confirm changing theme did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here. I can avoid images not being created by not using 'drush cr' but clicking 'admin > config > performance > clear caches' instead.

(Drush Version 8.0.5)

Answer (score 2):

**Missing 'itok' token in the query string**

Since [Drupal 7.20 release](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.20-release-notes) image styles will not be generated unless the request includes a valid 'itok' token in the query string. (apparently this was DoS protection)

So if you upload a new image example.png and the theme does not use [image_style_url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7.x) to generate the img src for an image style, you may be missing the token and the image style will not be generated.

Answer (score 0):

For me the images were being uploaded to just the /files directory but wasn't generating in the styles folder for one of the image styles. all my permissions were correct too. This started happening after i updated my media module which did alot of updates from 1.x to 2.x --- what i found out was that the image style wasn't even created, which was why it wasnt showing up in the directory. Check your image styles page to make sure its there!