# Image styles are not getting created

Tags: 7, media

Our image styles are not getting created on one of the Drupal 7 sites in a multi-site installation. They are created for at least one of the other sites that uses the same Drupal 7 core.

Symptoms: Upon uploading an image to a node, the image preview does not get displayed (depending on the browser, a broken image placeholder may display). The image is not created in the file system either. I have verified file system ACLs. Both sites use the same .htaccess.

Comment: Do any errors appear in logs?

Comment: watchdog just gives me a "page not found" error; the apache error logs don't show any errors.

Comment: What does the status report say (admin/reports/status)

Comment: What am I looking for? I don't see anything related to 'image' or 'style' on either the working or broken sites. "The GD toolkit is installed and working properly" on both sites.

Comment: I did just notice something really wierd though. Both sites use the same core, and neither site needs to run updates, but the working site isn't picking up a large number of available updates (admin/reports/updates/update), even after checking manually. Huh.

Answer (score 0):

As per [image style (imagecache) images are not being created](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54746/image-style-imagecache-images-are-not-being-created), changing the theme and reverting back fixed the problem. Very strange - it would be nice to know what the cause was!