# Image Styles not creating on one custom style only

Tags: 7, theming, media, emails

I've run into this issue where we have created a custom style (emailthumb) which is to be used when sending out email newsletters via simplenews. The thumbnail is based on 'thumbnail' style but is slightly bigger. It works fine when the image is being rendered as thumbnail or any other style but not the one custom style.

The permissions of the folders are all exactly the same (I've even tried 777 for emailthumb->public) as in thumbnail but there is no pictures folder being created. I then get a log error of access denied as the URL to the image as the folder doesn't exist.

http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/emailthumb/public/pictures/image.jpg

I have tried changing the theme as per
[image style (imagecache) images are not being created](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54746/image-style-imagecache-images-are-not-being-created)
but this has not worked.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Current Permissions
sites/default 555

Comment: anything in the watchdog (recent log messages) ? anything in the apache (or other webserver) log ?

Comment: might be on to something there. drush watchdog-show, and error log show the same 'access denied' with the url including the pictures folder that doesn't exits. Server error log shows
Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/domain/public_html/sites/default/

Comment: looks like a permissions problem.

Comment: Ok I've added the current permission of the default folder. Is this where the problem lies?

Comment: changing sites/default to 755 removes the server errors but nothing else has changed. Tried deleting and adding the style again and also swapping the theme over. No effect

Comment: can your apache user write to sites/default/files/styles/ ?

Comment: This is where I start getting lost. Owner and Group can, owner being the apache user?

Comment: It depends on your setup. But yes apache could be the owner of sites/default/files . That should work. The main thing is that apache can write to sites/default/files

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the image style was never being called to save the image in the first place. The following code forces the image to save for this use case.

```
function MODULE_node_presave($node){
  // Get some field items from a field called 'field_image.
  if ($image_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image')) {
    $image_item = array_shift($image_items);

    // Load the associated file.
    $file = file_load($image_item['fid']);

    // An array of image styles to create.
    $image_styles = array('emailthumb');

    foreach ($image_styles as $style_name) {
      // Get the location of the new image.
      $derivative_uri = image_style_path($style_name, $file->uri);
      $style = image_style_load($style_name);
      // Create the image.
      image_style_create_derivative($style, $file->uri, $derivative_uri);
    }
  }
}
```

credit here [force image style generation on save node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54581/force-image-style-generation-on-save-node)