# Image styles are not beeing generated

Tags: 8

I have a problem where Drupal tries to access the files in the "styles/stylename" directory, but they are not there since they aren't beeing generated. I allready tried changing the theme for a while ([image style (imagecache) images are not being created](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54746/image-style-imagecache-images-are-not-being-created)) and also tried creating the style folder, changing permission and editing the .htacces file (https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2015-06-16/image-styles-not-generating#comment-11859066). I also tried a few other things, nothing seems to work.
 
 
Maybe usefull information: the images are created in a directory based on the month and year. 

 for example "sites/default/files/2019-07/filename.png"

edit:
When accessing the url of the image style it returns:

> Error: Class 'lsolesen\pel\PelJpeg' not found in Drupal\file_mdm_exif\Plugin\FileMetadata\Exif->getFile() (line 108 of modules/file_mdm/file_mdm_exif/src/Plugin/FileMetadata/Exif.php).
>       Drupal\file_mdm_exif\Plugin\FileMetadata\Exif->getFile() (Line: 127)
>       Drupal\file_mdm_exif\Plugin\FileMetadata\Exif->doGetMetadataFromFile() (Line: 280)
>       Drupal\file_mdm\Plugin\FileMetadata\FileMetadataPluginBase->loadMetadataFromFile() (Line: 377)
>       Drupal\file_mdm\Plugin\FileMetadata\FileMetadataPluginBase->getMetadata('Orientation') (Line: 183)
>       Drupal\file_mdm\FileMetadata->getMetadata('exif', 'Orientation') (Line: 39)
>       Drupal\image_effects\Plugin\ImageToolkit\Operation\gd\AutoOrient->execute(Array) (Line: 172)
>       Drupal\Core\ImageToolkit\ImageToolkitOperationBase->apply(Array) (Line: 124)
>       Drupal\Core\ImageToolkit\ImageToolkitBase->apply('auto_orient', Array) (Line: 143)
>       Drupal\Core\Image\Image->apply('auto_orient') (Line: 138)
>       Drupal\image_effects\Plugin\ImageEffect\AutoOrientImageEffect->applyEffect(Object) (Line: 302)
>       Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle->createDerivative('public://2018-05/02_1.jpg', 'public://styles/project_gallery_image/public/2018-05/02_1.jpg') (Line: 161)
>       Drupal\image\Controller\ImageStyleDownloadController->deliver(Object, 'public', Object)
>       call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
>       Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 582)
>       Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
>       Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
>       Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 151)
>       Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
>       Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
>       Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>       Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
>       Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
>       Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>       Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
>       Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
>       Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 693)
>       Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Comment: Try access url of image style and provide message error.

Comment: @Jonh When accessing the url over the browser, it returns: "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Comment: You need to follow [topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127182/how-do-i-enable-developer-debug-mode) to show error message. a

Comment: I think you have problem with install image affect. Let using composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to installed missed library by the following comment on the root of your drupal website :

```
composer require drupal/image_effects:^2
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this fixxed the main issue. I still have a problem where the image style generator tries to get files uploaded with uppercase extensions, from a lowercase source and throws an error like "Image generation failed. source file missing". But I belive thats a completely different issue.

Comment: @Bruhno you're welcome . please ask it in another question and give more details about that. I'm here to help the other Drupalist